# Can't get simple (no encryption) php forgot password form to work

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

Well, I have been at it with an php/mysql authentication system for weeks, piecing it together from tutorials and learning as I go. I am now at a tricky part which is the password `forgot.php` page. I have little experience with `phpmail`, and there seems to be many few things fundamentally wrong with this code.

First off, since I added the code about the `phpmail` info, the page is just blank. But even when it was working, the page would just go blank after a user hit submit. Not sure what is keeping the form from even displaying. Also, not sure if I am going about this at correctly in terms of a working php password forgot email form.

Code on login.php:

```
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
Remember me: <input type="checkbox" name="remember" /><br />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
<a href="forgot.php">Forgot Password?</a>




<?php
session_start();
require_once("functions.php");
require_once("db-const.php");
require("class.phpmailer.php");


$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['password'] = $password;

if (logged_in() == true) {
redirect_to("profile.php");
}

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Forgot your Username or Password?</title>
</head>
<body>  
<h1>Forgot your Username or Password?</h1>

<p>Please enter your email address below.</p>
<form action="forgot.php" method="post">
Email: <input type="text" name="email" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
## connect mysql server
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
# check connection
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
exit();

}


## query database
# fetch data from mysql database
$sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email LIKE '{$_POST['email']}' LIMIT 1";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
$user = $result->fetch_array();
} else {
echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}</p>";
exit();
            }



$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host     = "smtp.practice.com"; // SMTP server

$mail->From     = "support@practice.com";

$mail->Subject  = "login information";
$mail->Body     = "Hello, here is your login information. User name is: $username and your    
password is $password;"
$mail->WordWrap = 50;


if ($result->num_rows == 1) {

echo "<p>Login credentials have been sent to <b>{$_POST['email']}</b></p>";
} else {
echo "<p>Sorry, no user found with this email.</p>";
}
}
?>
<a href="login.php">Login</a> | <a href="register.php">Register</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you running this on localhost?

Comment: I recommend you research "SQL injection" before using this code in production.

Comment: Hi Jody, Yes, I'm running localhost on a godaddy web server. I did read about SQL injection. Not to worried about using a live environment as I am doing all this just to learn for now and not worried about hacking. What is the alternative? Mamp?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there's a lot wrong with your code, as others have pointed out.

- You're creating a message before you know if the user exists.
- You're vulnerable to SQL injection.
- You're not sending the message (no call to `$mail->send();`)
- You're using an old version of PHPMailer.
- The message you are constructing contains the username and password
  the user submitted, not the username and password you got from the database.
- I do hope you're not keeping the password in plain text in the DB!
- Blank screens ususally mean PHP errors - call `ini_set('display_errors', true);`

In general you're reinventing the wheel and not gaining much in the process. If you really want an working auth system (and this is not just a coding exercise), I suggest you take a look at the [php login project](http://www.php-login.net).